# Redmine - subprojects list order

Tags: ruby, redmine

I would like to change an order of the subprojects shown on /projects page. Currently I have main projects list ordered by 'created_on' descending and for each one - a subproject list ordered by 'id' ascending. What I want to do is to sort subprojects also by 'created_on' date. I gave a quick look on models and controllers of Redmine source but my knowledge of Ruby is a bit low and it's hard work without it. My guess is I need to make a change in /app/models/project.rb but not sure what kind of change it must be, yet. It's 1.4.4 version of Redmine.

Any advices are very desired :)

Thanks